# Lubuntu 20.04 keeps trying to use two monitors even if a secondary monitor is unplugged, settings reset after reboot

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics, monitor

### Problem details

I used to use a second monitor ages ago, but I do not use it anymore. I never want again to use a second monitor.

The second phantom non-existing unplugged monitor is used by default to extend my screen. This causes problems on boot. Sometimes I can not see a lock screen, sometimes my system hangs with a black screen.

### What I need

1. Remove the second phantom non-existing unplugged monitor settings.
2. Make changes to be persistent.

### What I tried

Saving "**Monitor Settings**" not working. After reboot I see a phantom unplugged monitor as "enabled" again extending my screen to nowhere.

### System

- Lubuntu 20.04
- Notebook Samsung RC528

[image: phantom unplugged monitor]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like following the [Disabling phantom monitor](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xrandr#Disabling_phantom_monitor) documentation removed a phantom monitor from settings.

Commands I executed:

```bash
xrandr --output VGA1-1-2 --off
```

As a second step, I created a file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf`:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "VGA1-1-2"
    Option "Ignore" "true"
EndSection
```

Comment: Could you please add some details to your answer that demonstrate the specific steps you tool to resolve the issue? Link only answers are not encouraged on AU...